# Error with querydsl and mongodb : NoClassDefFoundError Predicate

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, querydsl

I am started to use with querydsl for mongodb,
I find some examples on web and tried to use it,
my pom.xml looks like (maybe there is some mistakes in versions...):

...

```
<!-- Versions -->
    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.data.jpa.version>1.2.0.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version>
        <spring.data.mongo.version>1.0.3.RELEASE</spring.data.mongo.version>
        <spring.amqp.version>1.0.0.RELEASE</spring.amqp.version>
        <slf4j-version>1.6.1</slf4j-version>
        <org.cloudfoundry-version>0.8.0</org.cloudfoundry-version>
        <querydsl.version>2.3.3</querydsl.version>
    </properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- CloudFoundry -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cloudfoundry</groupId>
        <artifactId>cloudfoundry-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>${org.cloudfoundry-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Cglib is a powerful, high performance and quality Code Generation
        Library, It is used to extend JAVA classes and implements interfaces at runtime. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Querydsl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.code.morphia</groupId>
                <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Database pooling -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Joda Time -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- apache commons -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Javax Servlet. This needs to be included for runtime only! -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Data Mapper package is a high-performance data binding package built
        on Jackson JSON processor -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson is a high-performance JSON processor (parser, generator) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate and JPA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.java-persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpa-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-cr-1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate Validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL Connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.16</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MongoDB Java Driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.data.jpa.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Data MongoDB -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.data.mongo.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring RabbitMQ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.amqp.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Ehcache -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

After deploy web app to server I get this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysema/query/types/Predicate
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1855)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:227)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:930)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:903)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:844)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:786)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474)
... 25 more
```

What is wrong ?

My repository is:

```
public interface IDomainRepository extends MongoRepository<Domain, String>{
}
```

when I add to it QueryDslPredicateExecutor like :

```
public interface IDomainRepository extends MongoRepository<Domain, String>,
    QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Domain>{
}
```

it's error ->NoClassDefFoundError->Predicate.

Tnx

Comment: Any update on the issue?

Comment: noooo, maybe in next try ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querydsl dependencies are not transitive here. I suggest to remove the optional=true from querydsl-mongodb.

The Querydsl version seems to be ok, but very old.

Comment: I changed Querydsl version to 3.1.0, but it's still the same error.

Comment: Querydsl 3.1.0 won't be compatible if you don't upgrade the other dependencies, did you remove the optional flag?

Comment: Yes I removed it, but still the same error, can you instruct me what are the new one and compatible versions ? Tnx.

Comment: Spring Data Mongodb 1.2.0.RELEASE and Querydsl 2.9.0 should work. Does the mvn:dependency-tree output reveal anything weird?

Comment: I change to these version, but if I use with QueryDslPredicateExecutor ( see addition in my question ), I get the error. It's sounds like in the server something missing...

Comment: Can you see the Querydsl Predicate and Expression classes on your classpath?

Comment: Hi I check this example and it's work https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-document-examples/tree/master/mongodb-music